# Can we share stuff directly to a Google+ page?

Tags: google-plus-pages

If I really want to share some stuff to my Google+ Page I have to manually visit my Plus Page, find the page section, find my corresponding page admin section, and finally get to post something.

Just wondering if there is an alternative of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bookmarklet to post a page directly to a Google+ page.

After some tinkering, this code for a bookmarklet works nicely to post directly to a Google+ page:

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/xxxxx/share?ur\l='+encodeURIComponent(location), 'Share to Google+','width=600,height=460,menubar=no,location=no,status=no'));
```

Replace the `xxxx` with the first number in your Google+ page's URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is new:

**[Introducing Buffer for Google+](http://blog.bufferapp.com/introducing-buffer-for-google-plus-pages-scheduling-posting-social-media)**

The easiest way to post to your Google+ Business Page! 
Also scheduling works really well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the website hosting the content that you want to share already has a Google+ sharing button (and many already do, together with sharing buttons for other social media services), then simply use that button.

A more general solution is to install a **Google+ bookmarklet** in your browser (such as [this one](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-plus-one-bookmarklet/19474/), from labnol.org), and to use that.